# How can I vertically align items in an unordered html list?

Tags: css, html-lists, center, vertical-alignment

How can I vertically align items in an unordered list to work in IE6 and 7?

I can't just set line-height to the full height because I have both 1 row items and 2 row items.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {
                list-style: none;
                border: 1px solid black;
                height: 40px;
            }
            li {
                float: left;
                margin-right: 10px;
                height: 40px;
                width: 46px;
            }
            a {

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/">item1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">two lines</a>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean to have that `</div>` in there?

Comment: That </div> in the li shouldn't be there.  Not sure if that is causing your problems.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot float your items to the left and expect them to vertically line up....

Remove

```
float: left;
```

From the LI style...

Comment: I need all items to be of the same width.
That's why I'm using float instead of display:inline.
Items with two words should take two rows.
Is it possible to achieve this without float?

Comment: Yes, you can... you need to remove the width limitation for the listed items set it to simply auto or 100%.

Comment: using width:auto will make all items appear in one line.
I want all the items to have the same width.
Items with long text should span two rows.

Comment: You first need to remove the float: left; and replace with with clear: both; or display: block; ... edit ...

I misunderstood what exactly you were attempting ... 

To separate the "words" by a "space" cannot be done dynamically within CSS, you would need to perform this action using javascript. In which it will explode words seperated by a "space" and break them into seperate listed items.

Comment: using float and width I can make the word split to two rows.

Comment: I believe this is a bit of confusion here, let me try and clarify a few things. You are attempting to horizontally display listed items, where a item with "two or more" words are broken down vertically. Using a left float and width it is perfectly possible, but not recommended as once you begin to tile these listed items IE will not play very nicely with a lists that have uneven heights and float ... You may either 1) Set a height large enough to accommodate the amount of words you expect. 2) Use javascript to adjust the lists accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly you want to use the float to shrink wrap the li?

If thats the case you need to set

```
li {clear:left;}
```

So the lis are below each other, not next to each other. You can also use inline-block if you want the li to shrink wrap to the content.

Also, depending on the goal of this, it might be approproate to use a table, depending on what it will be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this isn't a proper answer, but it may help clear things up:

Why are you using floats instead of `display: inline` for your list items?

Answer (score 0):

The rows  essentially be the same height. So there is no way to effectively "merge cells" in table speak. You should set the line height to the height of the "two line" items and then use the vertical-align property to align them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a horizontally displayed list where each item has a set width and height, but the text inside is vertically centred, and there may be items that have two lines of text.

If you know pre-rendering which items will be two lines you can apply the a CSS class that sets the `line-height: 40px;` only on those items with a single line. This is not normally the case thought, so the best way to go is to use JS to dinamically alter the line-height after the list has been rendered.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UEsAS/2/

In essence, alter your CSS to not set a height on the `li`s (this will cause them to be have a lower height if they are one-line, which is how you can detect which ones to alter). Then run the following (assuming jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var maxHeight = 40;
    $('li').each(function(i, el) {
        if ($(el).height() < maxHeight) {
            $(el).css('line-height', maxHeight + 'px');
        }
    });
});​
```